# How to toggle a .click easier?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am working on my final for my webpage development class, I am trying to make a blog themed website. I want to make my code it so that there is a profile picture and when clicked it turns into a box and reveals a bio and some other info. I already have that part done, but now I want to make it so that when the profile picture is clicked again, it will make the box and the info disappear. I understand that there are ways and I have tried some but to no success. When I try .toggle, it just disappears it completely. Any advice would help, thank you

(JSfiddle wasn't working for me, sorry) >
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/JoshuaHurlburt/pen/OVRdje)

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#picback').click(function() {
    $('#picback').animate({
      borderTopLeftRadius: 100,
      borderTopRightRadius: 100,
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 2,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 2,
      height: 460
    }, 'slow');
    $('#info').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: So you've tried $('#info').fadeToggle('slow')?

Comment: We're in 2015. This really should be done with no Javascript or jQuery involved. Pure CSS and HTML solution is easy to implement. Use transitions!

Comment: Find my pure HTML/CSS solution below.

Comment: Sou you got seven answers within 30 minutes. And none of them solves your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing `px` unit values at `css` , `js` ; checking for `display` property of `$("#info")` at `click` of `#picback` to fade in , fade out `#info` ; reset `#picback` `css` back to initial `borderRadius` , `height`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var picback = $("#picback")
  , info = $("#info");
  picback.click(function() {
    if (info.css("display") === "none") {
      $(this).animate({
        borderTopLeftRadius: 100,
        borderTopRightRadius: 100,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 2,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 2,
        height: 460
      }, 'slow');
      info.fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      $(this).animate({borderRadius:120,height:230}, 'slow');
      info.fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
#picback {
  background-color: #B8B8B8;
  border-radius: 120px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
}
#picback:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px black;
}
#profilepic {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 5px;
}
#name {
  font-family: 'Playball', cursive;
  color: blue;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px white;
}
#age {
  font-family: 'Pragati Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#bio {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
#info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#'>
  <div id='picback'>
    <img src='https://www.shoptab.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/profile-circle.png' id='profilepic'>
    <div id='info'>
      <h2 id='name'>Joshua T. Hurlburt</h2>
      <h2 id='age'>15</h2>
      <p id='bio'>My name is Josh. I attend school as a freshman at Rhinelander High School. This is a project I made for my Web Page Development Final.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGKepE

Answer (score 4):

We're in 2015. Javascript or jQuery is **not** needed here!

Use CSS transitions and make use of :checked pseudo class. This way you can also easily set an initial state.

Fully working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJrvXo

```css
#visibleToggle {
  display: none;
}
#picback {
  background-color: #B8B8B8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}
#picback:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#profilepic {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 16px;
  left: 2px;
}
#profilepic:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#name {
  font-family: 'Playball', cursive;
  color: blue;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px white;
}
#age {
  font-family: 'Pragati Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#bio {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
#info {
  opacity: 0;
}
#visibleToggle:checked + #picback {
  border-radius: 120px 120px 2px 2px;
  height: 460px;
}
#visibleToggle:checked + #picback #info {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="visibleToggle" />
<div id='picback'>
  <label for="visibleToggle">
    <img src='https://www.shoptab.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/profile-circle.png' id='profilepic' />
  </label>
  <div id='info'>
    <h2 id='name'>Joshua T. Hurlburt</h2>
    <h2 id='age'>15</h2>
    <p id='bio'>My name is Josh. I attend school as a freshman at Rhinelander High School. This is a project I made for my Web Page Development Final.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would recommend:

- Instead of performing the animations in jQuery on click, give an active class to the picture element when clicked.
- Perform your animations with CSS only when the picture has the active class.
- Remove the class if you click on the picture element and it exists.

I would love to give you actual code, but since it's for your final, this should give you a good starting place :) Best of luck!

Comment: This answer makes a lot more sense now that CSS animations are more widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

You should use .toggleClass() for click in the image and control the states of bio (for example collapsed and expanded) directly in css.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is use a closure function that remembers its state:

```
var clickHandler = (function () {
    var isOpen = false;
    return function () {
        isOpen = !isOpen; // Toggles between true and false
        if (isOpen) {
            $('#picback').animate({
                borderTopLeftRadius: 100,
                borderTopRightRadius: 100,
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 2,
                borderBottomRightRadius: 2,
                height: 460
            }, 'slow');
            $('#info').fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            // Add close animation here
        }
    };
})();

$('#picback').click(clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a very simple solution. Other examples posted already are a bit sexier, but I just used a variable to check whether or not it's open or closed. I also added in the basic closing animation, but you'll want to fiddle with that to make it not terrible. For example I'd suggest resetting the border radius in the callback after the animation function to prevent that ugly oval effect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dropped = false;
  $('#picback').click(function() {
    if (!dropped) {
      $('#picback').animate({
        borderTopLeftRadius: 100,
        borderTopRightRadius: 100,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 2,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 2,
        height: 460
      }, 'slow');
      $('#info').fadeIn('slow');
      dropped = true;
    } else { // Closing animation
      $('#picback').animate({
        borderRadius: "50%",
        height: "230px"
      }, 'slow');
      $('#info').fadeOut('slow');
      dropped = false;
    }
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dopaJq

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It adds a class when animated and then checks for it before animating.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#picback').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('animated')) {
      $this.removeAttr('style').removeClass('animated');
    } else {
      $this.animate({
        borderTopLeftRadius: 100,
        borderTopRightRadius: 100,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 2,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 2,
        height: 460
      }, 'slow').addClass('animated');
      $('#info').fadeIn('slow');

    }
  });
});
```